# Issue with UITextfield into a NSMutableArray

Tags: ios

I had this working using NSArray until I realize I need to insert a string into array. Now I'm changing this to a NSMutableArray, but having issues with my syntax. Am I allowed to use componentsJoinedByString in NSMutable arrays?

```
    NSString *item;
    int numofSeg;
    int needSeg;
if (textfield.text == @"::") {
        numofSeg = 0;

    }
    NSMutableArray *dlist = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    //take string from textfield and split it into a list on colons.
    dlist = [textfield.text componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
    //run through list to count how many segments. Non blank ones.
    for (item in dlist) {
        if (item != @""){
            numofSeg = numofSeg + 1;
            NSLog(@"%@",numofSeg);
        }
    }
    //determine number of segments
    needSeg = 8 - numofSeg;
    while (needSeg > 0) {
        //insert 0000 at blank spot
        [dlist insertString:@"0000" atIndex:@""];
        needSeg = needSeg - 1;
    }
    for (item in dlist) {
        if (item == @"") {
            //remove blank spaces from list
            [dlist removeAllObjects:item];
        }
    }
    //join the list of times into a string with colon
    NSString *joinstring = [dlist componentsJoinedByString:@":"];
    NSLog(@"%@",joinstring);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out.  This is what I ended up using to fix this:

```
NSString *z = @"0000";
z =  [z stringByAppendingString:@""];
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `NSMutableArray` has a method called `insertString:atIndex:`. You should probably use `insertObject:atIndex:` instead.

What error do you get exactly?

**Edit:**

If you only use the `NSMutableArray` to insert `@"0000"` before `@" "`, then you can simply do:

```
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@" 0000"];
```

or something like that. No need to use `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: My main issue was trying to use componentsJoinedByString in NSMutableArray.  I kind of have it working now, but converting it back to NSArray.  I need to basically insert a string at a Index of string @"".  Not at a index:0. This is what i'm using for NSArray *item = [ipv6display.text componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

Comment: I basically need to figure out how to take the MutableArray dlist and insert a sttring at a blank space.  [dlist insertString:@"0000" atString:@""];.  In Python I was able to write it like this:  list1.insert(list1.index(''),'0000')

Comment: what do you mean by "at a Index of string @"""? Can you give me an example of what you want to do? And what problem do you run into exactly?

Comment: From the mutablearray list. I need to insert a string "0000" when a blank space occurs.  The above is my example(which insertString atIndex doesn't work for me).I also wrote a example in python that works.

Comment: You can do `indexOfObject:@""` to get the index of @" ", and then do `insertObject:atIndex:` at the index you just obtained.